# Load .so from /system/lib android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, .so

We have a 3rd party vendor which manufactures android devices. For which
they have native libraries which are packaged in /system/lib...

Now while developing android applications, I have to use there .so files.
But when I use `System.load("/system/lib/*.so")` I get

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Now when I package this .so files in my jni folder under armeabi, I am able to load the .so file using `loadLibrary("name")`

But the problem is there are many .so files and I don't want to package them with all the apk which I develop for our devices.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem.

I've found about the [Nougat behaviour](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk) changes...  And tried changing the compileSDKversion to 23 and gradle version 2.2.0, my device is running on Android 4.4

Comment: compileSDKversion dies not matter here. If your device API is below Nougat, you don't have to worry about their protection of system libraries. You have 
a different problem: on 4.4 you may need to explicitly load libraries in dependency order. E.g. if libA.so depends on libB.so and on libC.so, try to System.load() libB.so and libC.so before you System.load(libA).

Comment: Hmm... But when I bundle the single .so file with my apk... It works..

Comment: Check logcat maybe you can find more hints.